# Can my son use my Gmail account for Pokémon Go without his Android accessing my emails?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I installed pokemon go on my phone for my son. It's logged in with my Gmail account. I have now bought my son his own phone.  Is there a way to log into the game using my Gmail account without all my emails etc. showing on his phone? I never set up a separate username account and have only ever logged in using Gmail. He obviously doesn't want to start at the beginning again.

Comment: You can turn off sync of emails/contacts, in the account section of your phone, but he can simply turn it back on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Sir that is not possible.
You will have to make a new account for your son.

Answer (score -1):

Your e-mails should not show up on his phone if you log in to the game with your account. Pokemon GO only uses your basic profile info and e-mail address.

For example, my iPhone currently has two different Google accounts logged in to Ingress and Pokemon GO, and the mail app is connected to a third Google account. Android should be no different.

But if you still have doubts, you could always go the new account route.

Comment: Android Pokemon Go is different. It uses the system login account.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie you can [have multiple Google accounts logged in on a single device](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-manage-multiple-google-gmail-accounts-android/), so I don't think it's not possible to have a different Google account logged-in for e-mail and the game.

Comment: @陽炎型駆逐艦磯風 On the article you link, it also says that some android apps can only accept a single login per device (Facebook, Dropbox, etc.). Is Pokemon Go one of them?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple on Android, but it works very differently from how multiple accounts for different apps work on iOS. iOS experience is simply not relevant to this question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The original question didn't mention Android either, so I thought it was fair game (at the time).

Comment: Fair enough! I don't see them anymore, but I believe that was clarified in comments.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie There was? I didn't see comments on the question when I made that answer.